# How to kick start web services after publishing using powershell script or any other way

Tags: web-services, powershell, autostart, octopus-deploy

I am currently using Octopus to publish web services. Is there any way to start the services after publishing it automatically using power shell script or any other way.

Thanks

Comment: Which services? If you are talking about IIS just add `IISReset /force` or `Restart-Service w3svc`(which is _not_ the recommended way) to your postdeploy script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get IIS site to start up automatically after deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983696/how-to-get-iis-site-to-start-up-automatically-after-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to spin up your app pool so that the first request doesn't take longer than normal, you can issue the following in your post-deploy.ps1

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost/SomeTestPage"
```

Of if you have .NET 4:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series